# Pip unable to open outgoing socket when inside virtualenv in cygwin

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip

I'm getting a windows error when I try to use pip or easy_install inside virtualenvs.  cygwin/python 2.7/windows 7

```
*** error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

This error shows up in other questions on SO, but they're all related to people trying to listen to port 80.  In my case I'm trying to connect out, to port 80/443 - which shouldn't be nearly as restricted.

I *can* use pip with the main python, just not with the one in the virtualenv, so I don't think it's a library problem.  The following is a test run, done in a console2 window with admin privileges.

```
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/Python27/python
```

I *can* reach pypi here:

```
$ pip install 
Downloading/unpacking django from https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Dj....
ctl^c

virtualenv --version
1.11.4
```

making the virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv testenv
New python executable in testenv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

$ source testenv/Scripts/activate
```

virtualenv is really activated.  (can see sys.path is different when running the new python)

```
(testenv)$ which python
/cygdrive/c/proj/testenv/Scripts/python

(testenv)$ which pip
/cygdrive/c/proj/testenv/Scripts/pip

(testenv)$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from C:\proj\testenv\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

(testenv)$ pip install django
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

Place breakpoint at c:\python27\Lib\socket.py : 576

```
(testenv)$ pip install django
```

the relevant code from around here in socket.py:

```
res=getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM)
res
>>> [(2, 1, 0, '', ('103.245.222.184', 443))]
af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res[0]

sock = socket(af, socktype, proto)
sock
>>> <socket._socketobject object at 0x020505E0>
```

socket is created ok.

```
sock.connect(sa)
*** error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

socket library fails.

Since everything works except for the virtualenv, I think that somehow virtualenv isn't creating the python in the right way, so that windows isn't giving it enough permissions to even connect out.

I have no anti-virus software running, and the problem occurs even when I turn off the windows firewall.

Permissions: testenv, testenv/Scripts are 755.  So is python & all exes in Scripts.  Any ideas?